# FirePHP replacement

Tags: php, firefox, debugging

As Firebug seems not to be supported in Firefox 50+, can someone please suggest a library other than FirePHP to use for debugging php variables in the web console?

I just need to log variables to the console. In PHP. Those are my only requirements. No "fancy stuff" like breakpoints, watchers etc. needed.

Comment: Not sure I understand.  I think my question is very specific - I need to be able to debug php variables in a web console.  That means that the library prints the contents of a variable to the browser and it is viewable in the console just like `console.log()` in javascript.  I realize some people may not understand that but I don't think it's my job to explain what vocabulary means - if someone doesn't understand what it means to debug variables in a web console then they surely won't be able to make any suggestions for software that does so.

Comment: Do you need breakpoints? Step-by-step processing? Setting "watches"? Marking which variables should be observed? Which part of code maybe is never touched, or is frequently touched? Anything else?

Comment: No, I just need to log variables to the console.  In PHP.  Those are my only requirements.  PHP.  Log variables to console.  They are both stated in my question.

Comment: OK, good luck then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 50+ has a default ChromeLogger:
https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug#Server_logs

and not supporting firePHP at this moment
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1335681
hope that the Mozilla will add firePHP to the Console, many functions in my projects using that, I must use Chrome at this time for debugging.

Comment: 7 months later.. finally made the switch to ChromePHP / ChromeLogger in Firefox.  Must say Firefox performance is much better without Firebug / FirePHP.